# Job Portal not opening

Tags: bug

Simply clicking on Jobs in the side menu gives the following:

[image]

Comment: Happens to me too. Clicking on a specific add in the right bar still works.

Comment: No repro currently. Maybe due to a massive change on the job page. Note that the unicorn vote is still not available.